# C# simple open source application

Tags: c#, open-source

C# simple open source desktop application to learn from?

I'm trying to learn C#, but most of the times I found tutorials for non programmers which are pretty boring, or comparission with other lenguages.

I tried to compile an application that look nice enough as to call my attention and simple enough ( at first glance ) as to be understood by me, but it turns out it [was developed in Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836767/using-mono-on-windows).

I've downloaded VS for C# express edition in the past, but didn't knew what to do next with it.

So my question is:

Does anyone knows about a simple open source Windows Application developed in C# I can learn from?

It doesn't have to be too simple, but most of the ones I've looked so far are pretty complex, since they are production ready.

Thanks

Comment: Keep in mind, developed in Mono does not mean "incompatible with MS .NET."  One of the problems is that WinForms, the de facto (not true EMCA) GUI standard is a bit behind on Mono partially because it's harder to implement on non-Windows platforms.  That led to GTK# and such.  If you're just trying to find /any/ cross-platform C# app with source code, I would try looking through Freshmeat (http://freshmeat.net/tags/c-3) and/or Google Code (http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label%3a.NET) and see what interests you.

Comment: In this particular case it was the Mono.Unix namespace

Answer (score 3):

If you dont mind wpf, try [BabySmash](http://www.hanselman.com/babysmash/)

Answer (score 1):

These aren't desktop applications but they are good open source web applications done mostly in C# that you could learn from.

http://www.asp.net/community/projects/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at [SourceForge](http://www.sourceforge.net) or [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com)?

Answer (score 1):

check out http://www.codeplex.com

Comment: Yea, thats the true! makes it easier to pick something that you are intressted in. The last piece I checked out was http://toastify.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of sample apps for both [winforms](http://windowsclient.net/downloads/folders/applications/default.aspx) and [WPF](http://windowsclient.net/downloads/folders/wpfsamples/default.aspx) over at [windowsclient.net](http://windowsclient.net/).  I'm not sure I would call any of them a reference application, but there sure are a lot of them. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had tremendous luck with Microsoft's SharePoint, and extending it was a lot of fun and very educational WRT c# and learning to use it.  Check out [pilothouseconsulting's](http://www.pilothouseconsulting.com/) development dvd for a lot of good initial information on setting up a debugger and such.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple [command line grep tool](http://code.google.com/p/jgrep/) I put on google code.  You may find that interesting.